# how to stop date change from one time zone to other

Tags: javascript, extjs, time, zone

I have a issue in stopping date change. 
Scenario: if an user booked an item in IST or GMT and another user is trying to see the same booking data in EST the time of booking is moving one day back to EST which should not happen. 
i need a solution to stop date change from frontend EXTjs and it has to display same date no matter in any time zone.
the server is located in EST.

Expected: item booked :2015/09/07 IST should save in database as 2015/09/07 in EST

Actual : item booked :2015/09/07 IST but saves in database as 2015/09/06 in EST
when user is trying to see the booked item some where in EST time zone it is moved one day back and display as 2015/09/06.

Can any one help me what to do???

Comment: For timezone consideration, it's good pratice to store GMT time in database so users can get actual time correspond to his/her timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following `dateFormat` in field declaration in model:

```
 {
        name: 'bookedDate',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-dTH:i:s'
    },
```

Comment: while saving the date in what format you are sending the date.It will be good if you share your code as i also faced this issue

Comment: Date format is used as yyyymmdd using date renderer as Gregorian calendar. I believe this wont be the main issue.

Comment: yeah that is not a problem,but in what format you are sending the date to server that matters

Comment: Its k found the solution i need converted all timezone to EST using Date.utils